# How to center this table header?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}

        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{Tipo de controle} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{Política} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{Estação} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{$ u_{1}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{$ t_{1}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{$ u_{2}$} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{$ t_{2}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{$ f_{1}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{$ f_{2}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{$ f_{3}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{$J$} & \multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{Eficiência} \\
        \midrule
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{Sem controle} & - & - & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1814,4 & 1814,4 & - \\
        \addlinespace 
        \hline
        \addlinespace 
        \multirow{8}{*}{\parbox{1.7cm}{\centering \textbf{Degrau Concomitante}}} & \multirow{4}{*}{1} & Primavera & 0,3702 & 90 & 0 & 0 & \multirow{4}{*}{135,91} & \multirow{4}{*}{-} & \multirow{4}{*}{100,56} & \multirow{4}{*}{236,47} & \multirow{4}{*}{77,84 \%} \\
        &  & Verão & 0,3848 & 87 & 0 & 0 & & & & & \\
        &  & Outono & 0,2020 & 47 & 0  & 0  & & & & & \\
        &  & Inverno & 0,0407 & 46 & 0  & 0  & & & & & \\
        \addlinespace 
        \cline{2-12}
        \addlinespace 
        & \multirow{4}{*}{2} & Primavera & 0 & 0 & 0,095 & 88 & \multirow{4}{*}{-} & \multirow{4}{*}{120,28} & \multirow{4}{*}{201,6}  & \multirow{4}{*}{321,88} & \multirow{4}{*}{57,7 \%} \\
        &  & Verão & 0 & 0 & 0,1151 & 71 & & & & & \\
        &  & Outono & 0 & 0 & 0,0971 & 44 & & & & & \\
        &  & Inverno & 0 & 0 & 0,4663 & 1 & & & & & \\
        \addlinespace
        \cline{2-12}
        \addlinespace 
        & \multirow{4}{*}{3} & Primavera & 0,1633 & 65 & 0,0748 & 90 & \multirow{4}{*}{61,51} & \multirow{4}{*}{54,75} & \multirow{4}{*}{49,38} & \multirow{4}{*}{165,64} & \multirow{4}{*}{82,51 \%} \\
        &  & Verão & 0,3646 &  52 & 0,0849  &  80 & & & & & \\
        &  & Outono &  0,3249 & 34 &  0,0131 & 84 & & & & & \\
        &  & Inverno &  0,0577 &  23 & 0,01 & 82 & & & & & \\
        \addlinespace
        \hline
        \addlinespace [![enter image description here][1]][1]
        \multirow{8}{*}{\parbox{1.7cm}{\centering \textbf{Decrescente Concomitante}}} & \multirow{4}{*}{1} & Primavera & 0,4572 & 90 & 0 & 0 & \multirow{4}{*}{97,93} & \multirow{4}{*}{-} & \multirow{4}{*}{58,07} & \multirow{4}{*}{156} & \multirow{4}{*}{84,32 \%} \\
        &  & Verão & 0,4472 & 86 & 0 & 0 & & & & & \\
        &  & Outono & 0,2038 & 57 & 0  & 0  & & & & & \\
        &  & Inverno & 0,8379 & 1 & 0  & 0  & & & & & \\
        \addlinespace 
        \cline{2-12}
        \addlinespace 
        & \multirow{4}{*}{2} & Primavera & 0 & 0 & 0,1158 & 90 & \multirow{4}{*}{-} & \multirow{4}{*}{99,66} & \multirow{4}{*}{95,04}  & \multirow{4}{*}{194,7} & \multirow{4}{*}{68 \%} \\
        &  & Verão & 0 & 0 & 0,1649 & 86 & & & & & \\
        &  & Outono & 0 & 0 &  0,0994 & 40 & & & & & \\
        &  & Inverno & 0 & 0 & 0,0490 & 22 & & & & & \\
        \addlinespace 
        \cline{2-12}
        \addlinespace 
        & \multirow{4}{*}{3} & Primavera & 0,2341 & 76 &  0,0801 & 79 & \multirow{4}{*}{37,29} & \multirow{4}{*}{24,11} & \multirow{4}{*}{ 23,44} & \multirow{4}{*}{84,84} & \multirow{4}{*}{88,63 \%} \\
        &  & Verão & 0,3139 &  88 & 0,092  &  48 & & & & & \\
        &  & Outono &  0,2906 & 24 &   0,0384 & 20 & & & & & \\
        &  & Inverno &  0,0335 & 26 & 0,0237 & 36 & & & & & \\
        \addlinespace 
\end{tabular}
```

I want to center this table header and the command \centering did not work. Any ideas? And I also want to center the text "Degrau Concomitante" and "Decrescente
Concomitante" in the merged cell. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Where is the table header?

Comment: @Bernard the first row is the header, isn't it?

Comment: No, they're the column headers, I would say. I thought you meant the caption. As is, your table can't fit the margins of a usual paper size.

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c} \centering \textbf{Tipo de controle} ` is completely wrong, the text should be in an argument, it would be `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Tipo de controle}} ` but the column is `c` anyway so you just want `\textbf{Tipo de controle}}` (and similarly all the other cases).

Comment: Small tip: `\begin{tabular}{*{12}{c}}` will give 12 `c` column types

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to remove your `multicolumn{1}{c}` completely, the centering inside the table as well, that should not be needed (thats what the c in the multicolumn is for).

You can just use `\textbf{Tipo de controle} &  \textbf{Política} &` (etc.) for the top rule. It will automatically center because of your `ccccccccccc` in the tabular.

For the verical alignment, it does not vertically align because you have 12 rows, and you define the multirow as `multirow{8}`, simply change that to `multirow{12}` and the vertical alignment is correct.